# angularjs, $http 304 error, modify data property

Tags: angularjs, http, frameworks, ionic-framework, etag

we are using the Ionic framework and AngularJS to create a mobile app with phone gap build. We have a call to our api to get an array of items using $http.get, we are adding an Etag in the header if we already have data in cache. 
If the data on the server has not changed we get a 304 error which is ok. We are having trouble modifying the data property on the response object form the server to our chached data in local storage.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

```
return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'http:example.com',
                params: params,
                headers: customHeader

                })                  
                .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    // do some stuff
                })

                .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    if(status == '304') {
                        alert('this data has not changed');
                        data = chachedData
                        // change data to chached data??



                    }

                });
```

Comment: Should error code 304 not trigger the success event as it has not failed

Answer (score 3):

HTTP 304 header code means **Not modified**, it's not an error. According to the RFC 2616 of HTTP 1.1, the server only sends back headers, not the response which tells the browser to use the response that it had already in cache.

It should be used to avoid heavy network traffic.

But in your case, if you want to do some cache invalidation, this is not the way (but I don't think this is what you wan't to do)

On the other hand, angular will always put 200 in status (even if it is a 304) and you shouldn't have to bother about keeping your data up to date, since you retrieve the fresher value each time (without bothering if it's from a cache in the server or fresh data from the server).

Comment: the error event does fire on a 304 status. AngularJS does not nativley support Etags so we need some way of managing the data our selves

Comment: On this code pen : what I was explaining http://codepen.io/topheman/pen/qdJONb - though, if you're on a previous angular version which considers 304 as errors, why don't you simply ignore the 304 responses (since you already have the data in your localStorage cache) ? To do that you would need to ignore the 200 that are catched in the error callback (I know, it weird ;-) - since angular won't supply you the 304 code, it will tell you, it's a 200 ... )

Comment: thanks for your help topheman. We must be on an older version of angular. i solved the problem using interceptors and assigning the cached data to the 304 response.