# Difference in response status codes in ajax call between client and server

Tags: angularjs, ajax, node.js, express

SetUp: - `Node/Express/Angular 1.x`

Problem - The response code received by client over the ajax call is 200 always (provided it is successful) irrespective of Server Response where response Headers gives 304 or 200 (checked in server console, browser networks response headers). Why do we have this difference?

On load of my application, following call is made from client code

```
getTeamInfo() {
        return this.$http
            .get(`${this.ApiUrl}`)
            .then((response) => {
                if (!response.data) {
                    console.log('could not obtain team information');
                } else {
                    //Always **200** for every successful response
                    console.log('TeamInfo Call status .. ', response.status); 
                    return response.data;
                }
            });
    }
```

Server has route setup like `app.use('/teams', teams.teamInfo);` where `teams = new TeamController();`

```
    function TeamController(){
       this.teamInfo= function(req, res){
            var teamsInfo = {};
            if(req.session && req.session.teams){
                teams = req.session.teams;
                teamsInfo = {
                    name: teams.attributes.name + ' - ' + teams.attributes.slogan
                };
            }
            //Express console gives GET /teams 304 or 200
            res.send(teamsInfo);
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

HTTP 304 is the code for `Not Modified`. Node.js automatically gives a 304 when the same resource is requested again and the response is unchanged. This saves you from having to send the same data twice.

ETA contents of my comment:

Reading the angular docs, I think angular parses all successful requests as 200. Add that to the fact that they've updated things so that it can automatically handle 304 statuses (giving you the same content as last time, probably down to the status) and you have Angular turning all of your 304 statuses into 200. For more discussion, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31598601/angularjs-http-304-error-modify-data-property).

Comment: Correct. But how does that explain that when NodeJS gives 304, The client still gets response.status=200?

Comment: Reading the angular docs, I think angular parses all successful requests as 200. Add that to the fact that they've updated things so that it can automatically handle 304 statuses, and you have it returning 200 for 304 no matter what. For more discussion, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31598601/angularjs-http-304-error-modify-data-property